# Cosa significa "senza in bocca due gommoni"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, vocabulary

L'ho sentito nella canzone di J-Ax "Il bello d'esser brutti", e dice così:

```
Col nasone ed i ciglioni, sono più bello di Brad Pitt
Senza in bocca due gommoni mandi a casa la Jolie
```

Cosa vuol dire "senza in bocca due gommoni", è una espressione particolare?
So che un gommone è tipo una barca gonfiabile, ma non so cosa vuol dire in questo senso della canzone.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avere in bocca due gommoni fa riferimento alle labbra di Angelina Jolie, molto pronunciate.

In senso dispregiativo significa aver fatto ricorso alla chirurgia plastica per avere labbra più grandi.

Espressione simile è ***avere due canotti al posto delle labbra***.